# XCode4 doesn't show "C/C++ Compiler Version" option

Tags: iphone, gcc, xcode4, llvm

We have a very rare problem.

In some machines we have installed the last version of xcode4 and works fine.

We can chose in `"C/C++ Compiler Version"` between *GCC* or *LLVM*, but in other machines with the same xcode4, we don't have "C/C++ Compiler Version" option, only **GCC_VERSION**, and obviously, we cant chose between LLVM or LLVM-GCC. The arrows don't appear.

We don't have any idea why the arrows don't appear in some machines, and it works great on other machines.

Any ideas??

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After try to install Xcode 4.0.1, without any result, we decided to make a downgrade to Xcode 3.2.6 and iOS SDK 4.3.

Wiht this version we can change between *LLVM-GCC or GCC* and the arrows appear.

But this isn't a good solution.

Any one have an idea about this issue on Xcode 4 wiht some machines ???